# CSS GRID - Create a blog layout

Tags: css, grid

[image]

I would like to have that layout with the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>left</p>
  <p>right 1</p>
  <p>right 2</p>
  <p>right 3</p>
  <p>right 4</p>
</div>
```

I can't change the HTML, can you help me achieve that with CSS grid?

https://jsfiddle.net/1y98feza/

Comment: Are you not allowed to add classes either?

Comment: is this school work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it if you absolutely can't use anything else:

```
div{
    display: grid;
}

p
{
    border: 5px solid #FF0000;
}

p:nth-child(1)
{
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 4 / span 1;
}

p:nth-child(2)
{
    grid-area: sidebar;
}
```